# Does the .Net RabbitMQ client work in a .Net Core 2.0. AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, aws-lambda, .net-standard

I am unable to open a connection to a RabbitMQ Cluster in AWS Lambda. I can connect to the cluster fine using the .Net Standard Library hosted in IIS. I get a BrokerUnreachableException with an InnerException of SocketException with ErrorCode -1 when hosting in in AWS Lambda.

**Exception Detail**

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error -1
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at PeopleGateway.Controllers.SalesforcePersonaNotificationsController.<GetAmpqBdsAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

The VPC is configured and I can open a socket to the same host and port within the Lambda function, but cannot use the RabbitMQ Client.

When running the same code locally using IIS Express the connection opens fine.

**Example Code**

```
   var cf = new ConnectionFactory();
   cf.Password = "password";
   cf.UserName = "username";
   cf.Port = 5672;
   string[] allHosts = new string[] { "hostname1.domain.com", "hostname2.domain.com" };
   var endpoints = allHosts.Select(h => new AmqpTcpEndpoint(h, cf.Port)).ToList();
   var conn = cf.CreateConnection(endpoints);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the AddressFamily needs to be set when running in Lambda:

```
var cf = new ConnectionFactory();
cf.Password = "password";
cf.UserName = "username";
cf.Port = 5672;
string[] allHosts = new string[] { "hostname1.domain.com","hostname2.domain.com" };
var endpoints = allHosts.Select(h => new AmqpTcpEndpoint(h, cf.Port)
                { AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork }).ToList();
   var conn = cf.CreateConnection(endpoints);
```